# Are there any command line tools for parsing coverage.xml and highlighting the missed lines?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, code-coverage, pytest

I'm working on python projects and generate coverage.xml for unit tests using the pytest-cov module. However I don't have any good tools to parse the coverage.xml and highlight which lines of code are missed. This seems to be a common use case but I can't find anything via google.

Are there any tools out there (preferably via command line since I work mostly over ssh) that does this?

I'm thinking of writing my own pygments filter if I can't find anything.

Comment: You don't like the html output produced by coverage html ?

Answer (score -3):

This script will help you along with pytest

http://nedbatchelder.com/code/coverage/